# Python FindLabel Function for Label Expression with Formatting Font?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, labeling

I originally had this `FindLabel` function (which works)...

```
def FindLabel ( [NAME], [Count_]  ):
  if [Count_] != None:
    return [NAME] +'\n' + "Well Log Count: " + [Count_]
```

I wanted to format the font of the second line only, after '\n', using formatting tags. This is what I tried, and it did not work...

```
def FindLabel ( [NAME], [Count_] ):
  if [Count_] != None:
   return"[NAME] +'\n' +  "<FNT name='Arial' size='13'>" & "Well Log Count: " + [Count_] & "</FNT>
```

I also tried to set a variable, and this did not work either...

```
def FindLabel ( [NAME], [Count_] ):
  myCount = "<FNT name='Arial' size='13'>" &  "Well Log Count: " + [Count_] & "</FNT>
  if [Count_] != None:
   return"[NAME] +'\n' +  myCount
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is python, and in your examples you're using the ampersand (&) to concatenate your string. You don't do this in the unformatted example that works. Use the plus sign - + - instead.Ampersand is used in VBScript.

Comment: No problem. In VBScript you can use either the ampersand or the plus sign to concatenate strings, but Python uses either the plus sign or commas - e.g. print 'a', 'b' - (at least as far as concatenating in this fashion; there are other methods, such as join(), etc. )